# Prevent access on users list on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently using [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) as my authorization gem on my Rails app. Basically, I created this page where in if you are admin (which means if a field has the `admin` value set up to `true) you can view this page and delete some existing user on the database via`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/users`

I already place this on my menu:

```
  <% if current_user.admin === true %>
                        <%= link_to "Users List", users_path, class: "dropdown-item #{active_class_white('/dashboard/contacts')}" %>
                    <% end %>
```

Which will hide this link if the user is not admin. However, this can be still access if the non-admin visits the url directly.

I've already set up my pundit file via `application_pundit.rb` file which contains the ff:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

Now I don't know what to do how to prevent other users that doesn't have the admin access to view this page and be able to delete any users from the database.

Please help.

UPDATE: I created a `user_policy.rb` and place the ff codes:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def index?
       user.admin? 
    end 

    def destroy?
      user.admin?
    end 
end
```

But this did not work as a non-admin can still access the page. What else should I do?

Comment: Which controller / controller action is handling this page (http://localhost:3000/dashboard/users)?

Comment: it is the `users_controller`

Answer (score 0):

In `user_policy`:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end

  def index?
    user.admin? 
  end 
end
```

In the context of Pundit, `user` is `current_user` so this will evalue to `true` if `user` is an admin (and to `false` otherwise).

And in your controller:

```
def index
  @users = policy_scope(User)
  authorize User
end
```

Comment: would you mind explaning what does class scope is working for?

Comment: Basically a `Scope` class is required by Pundit for views that need to authorize a listing of records. I suggest you read the official documentation for a detailed explanation:  https://github.com/varvet/pundit